# How do I create a table from a JSON object in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do is use Propublica's nonprofit API to pull in information about various nonprofits and display certain attributes in a table.

Right now, I'm fetching an object:

```
const [ orgs, setOrgs ] = useState({})

const fetchOrgs = async () => {
    const result = await Axios.get(`${API_URL}?state%5Bid%5D=${query}`)
    setOrgs(result.data.organizations)
  }
```

According to their API, organization objects are like this:

```
{
  "organization":{
    "id":142007220,
    "ein":142007220,
    "name":"PRO PUBLICA INC",
    "careofname":null,
    "address":"155 AVE AMERICA 13 FL",
    "city":"NEW YORK",
    "state":"NY",
    "zipcode":"10013-0000",
    "exemption_number":0,
    "subsection_code":3,
    "affiliation_code":3,
    "classification_codes":"1000",
    "ruling_date":"2008-02-01",
    "deductibility_code":1,
    "foundation_code":15,
    "activity_codes":"0",
    "organization_code":1,
    "exempt_organization_status_code":1,
    "tax_period":"2018-12-01",
    "asset_code":8,
    "income_code":8,
    "filing_requirement_code":1,
    "pf_filing_requirement_code":0,
    "accounting_period":12,
    "asset_amount":40988939,
    "income_amount":27237842,
    "revenue_amount":26685933,
    "ntee_code":"A20",
    "sort_name":null,
    "created_at":"2020-04-13T21:42:55.607Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-04-13T21:42:55.607Z",
    "data_source":null,
    "have_extracts":null,
    "have_pdfs":null
  },
```

This is my current function, which is not working:

```
const displayTable = () => {
    return (
      <Table striped border='true' hover='true' responsive='true'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>NTEE</th>
            <th>Income</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href=' '>Link</a></td>
          </tr>
          {Object.keys(orgs).map(({name, state, ntee_code, income_amount}, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{i + 1}</td>
              <td>{name}</td>
              <td>{state}</td>
              <td>{ntee_code}</td>
              <td>{income_amount}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }
```

When I run this, I get the test row, and then many rows of empty cells. Only the "#" column has anything, since it's just the index value. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated, I've only just started learning React and JS.

Comment: Looks like a typo: `result.data.organizations `should be `result.data.organization`

Comment: @jmargolisvt according to the API, using .organizations returns me an array of organization objects. This works when I check it by logging the response.

ref: https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/api#organization-object

Comment: I see. `Object.keys(orgs).map` looks suspicious.  Assuming you have an array of organization objects, you probably want just `orgs.map`.  It would be more helpful if you added the data structure you actually have in your state rather than the sample from the API.

Comment: looks like it's actually returning an array of objects. Not sure how to break into that second layer.

[ { city: "GARDEN GROVE", ein: 821016117, has_subseccd: true ...} ... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Organizations:</h1>
      <table style={{ width: '100%', textAlign: 'center', border: 'solid 1px' }}>
        <thead>
          <th>Index</th><th>Name</th><th>State</th><th>ntee_code</th><th>income_amount</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {orgs.map((organization, i) => {
             const org = organization.organization;
             return (
               <tr>
                 <td>{i}</td><td>{org.name}</td><td>{org.state}</td><td>{org.ntee_code}</td><td>{org.income_amount}</td>
               </tr>
             )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
```

I'm posting just the returned markup as I understood you have no problem with fetching the data, and you just don't know how to display.
Your solution had the right idea of iterating over the organization array to create `<tr>`s. But you didn't need the `Object.keys()` to access the values. You first need to iterate over the objects in the array, and then drill down each object using the `.` syntax: `const org = organization.organization;` and then e.g `org.name`.

Note that each of your objects actually has only one field, i.e `organization`, so you first need to drill into it and only then you can get the values further down the object tree. If you want to deconstruct the object in `map()` you can, and again you had the right idea about how it's done, you just got the layer wrong. So you can do

```
{orgs.map(({organization}, i) => {
  const { name, state, ntee_code, income_amount } = organization;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{i}</td><td>{name}</td><td>{state}</td><td>{ntee_code}</td><td>{income_amount}</td>
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

I hope it can help and it's all clear.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Can't believe it was something as simple as getting {} and [] mixed up...